# Why doesn't my compiler show my input operation about the linked list and with returned value 3221225477?

Tags: c, pointers, doubly-linked-list, dev-c++

I create the code to achieve a doubly linked list structure.However, I don't know why it doesn't show my expected output, even not print anything.
Here is the output of the compiler:
Process exited after 0.2849 seconds with return value 3221225477
But it shows 0 error and 0 warning.
Do you know anyting about the issue?
Thank you in advance!

here are my codes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//define a node
typedef struct ListNode
{
    int val;
    struct ListNode* left;
    struct ListNode* right;
} ListNode;
//define a function to insert node on the right
void insert_right(ListNode* p)
{
    ListNode* new_node = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    new_node->val = 0;
    new_node->right = p->right;
    p->right->left = new_node;
    p->right = new_node;
    new_node->left = p;
}
//define a function to insert node on the left
void insert_left(ListNode* p)
{
    ListNode* new_node = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    new_node->val = 0;
    new_node->left = p->left;
    p->left->right = new_node;
    p->left = new_node;
    new_node->right = p;
}
//move the p to the right by X
void move_right(int X, ListNode* p)
{
    int i; 
    for(i = 0; i < X; i++)
    {
        if (p->right != NULL)
        {
            p = p->right;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Right");
            break;
        }
    }
}
//move the p to the left by X
void move_left(int X, ListNode* p)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < X; i++)
    {
        if (p->left != NULL)
        {
            p = p->left;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Left");
            break;
        }
    }
}

//delete the node on the right of p
void remove_right(ListNode* p)
{
    if(p->right != NULL)
    {
        p->right->right->left = p;
        p->right = p->right->right;
    }
    else printf("Right");
}
//delete the node on the left of p
void remove_left(ListNode* p)
{
    if(p->left != NULL)
    {
        p->left->left->right = p;
        p->left = p->left->left;
    }
    else printf("Left");
}
//change the val of the node(p points to) to X
void set(int X, ListNode* p)
{
    p->val = X;
}
//show the value of the node which p points to
void show(ListNode* p)
{
    printf("%d", p->val);
}
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    //define the head_node and let p points to it
    ListNode* head = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    head->val = 0;
    head->left = NULL;
    head->right = NULL;
    ListNode* p = head;
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
    insert_left(p); 
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
    insert_right(p); 
    }
    move_left(2, p);
    move_right(30, p);
    show(p);
    printf("ha"); 
}
```

Comment: 3221225477 = 0xc0000005 = STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION. You have a bad pointer in your code, probably trying to dereference null. Run the code under a debugger in your IDE and it'll show you what and where. And no compile errors or warnings does not mean the code will run correctly.

Comment: Are you sure you get no warnings? You've declared `j` but never reference it, which is usually a compiler warning. I'd double check you have enabled warnings in your compiler flags.

Comment: What is the expected output? Do the functions `move_left` and `move_right` have any purpose? The don't have any side effect.

Comment: `p->left->left->right = p;` You only check `p->left!= NULL` what about `p` and `p->left-left`?

Comment: It really tells me 0 warning in DEV C++.
And the function I want is to make p moves, and show the node the p stops at, but it doesn't show it.
I debugged just now, and it shows a dialog box with'Program recieved signal SIGSEGV,Segmentation fault'

Comment: free (p->right); free(p->left); 
I added this, but it seems not to change`if(p->left != NULL)
 {
  p->left->left->right = p;
  free(p->left);
  p->left = p->left->left;
   
 }`

Comment: Run your program in a debugger. Check your pointers. Check for example, what is `p->left->right = new_node;` when you first call `insert_left`? Or more precise, what is `p->left`?

Comment: Thank you very much!
          I used code blocks to debug and found insert_left tobe wrong:                  `if(p->left != NULL)
    {
        p->left->right = new_node; //if p->left is NULL, we cant make it to have a p->left->right
    }`
         I added it and it runs now.         
(but i didnt free the room in remove_left becuase I think it's hard to free it after we give p->left->left to p->left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem of the first call of `insert_left(p);` as `head->left = NULL;` and, in `insert_left()` a `NULL` pointer is used in `p->left->right = new_node;`.

I suggest to use debugger and go line by line and check weather the variables follows your simple test data. It is very difficult to investigate memory overwriting in C or C++. It is important to always check that a pointer is `NULL` or not. There is one exception: if you checked before.

Comment: Yeah, it's really important. your advice is very Enlightening. Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 0):

The First problem is as you say the p->left may points to NULL.
And the other problem is in `move_left`and`move_right`, p can only be changed in the function, but it cannot be changed out of the function. so I should use the“pointer to pointer”.
just like this:

```
    //move the p to the right by X
    void move_right(int X, ListNode** p_ref)
    {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < X; i++)
        {
            if ((*p_ref)->right != NULL)
            {
                (*p_ref)= (*p_ref)->right;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Right");
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
//and in main func:

move_left(20, &p);
show(p);
move_right(30, &p);
```